# How to remove values in a column when it contains both numeric and non-numeric values?

Tags: r

I have a data set in which one column has got non-numeric as well as numeric values. I want to make a subset where I have values greater than 0 and I want to retain non-numeric values as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that example.  Try `v1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$col)); df1[v1 > 0 | is.na(v1),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the column to `numeric` (if it is a `character` class, just do `as.numeric(df1$col1)`, but if it is `factr`, then `as.numeric(as.character(df1$col1))`) and create a logical condition to subset the rows

```
v1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$col1))
df1[v1 > 0 | is.na(v1),] 
#   col1       col2
#1   24 -0.5458808
#2  asd  0.5365853
#4   d1 -0.5836272
#5    2  0.8474600
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(24, 'asd', -5, 'd1', 2), col2 = rnorm(5))
```

Comment: Thanks, but NAs will be inserted through coercion. How can I convert NAs back to non-numeric values?Sorry, I am new to R and this question might sound silly.

Comment: @AbhijitMishra  If you noticed the code, I created a different object `v1` and it is only used for subsetting the original dataset, so it is not converting anything on your original object